# Informatica Lookup & Update strategy error

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have trying a lookup and update strategy transformation but for some reason its not working.

I have a disconnected lookup in my mapping which is called based on a particular condition
and when the look up is null , I tried to set a variable to 'INS',REJ,UPD,DEL..

The new variable in my agg_trans-INS_UPD_DEL is not getting linked to the upd_strategy trans. I'm able to move the variable from expression to update_strategy but dont see the link being displayed..

[image]

Comment: I always used the aggregator trans..This is the expression Im using--IIF(ISNULL(LKP_DEPT_ID),IIF(EMP_GENDER='M','INS','REJ'),IIF(EMP_GENDER='M','UPD','DEL'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Aggregator is an active transformation.  if you are making a new port in aggregator, you wont be able to surpass this transformation for other ports while going to update strategy.

Without asking you for more of your functionality, you can fix this by simply flowing your ports through aggregator.  Whatever you need in update strategy, make sure they flow through aggregator...  Src Qualifier -> Aggregator -> Update Strategy.

I hope its clear enough, if not, think about going through documentation about active transformations..

Comment: As @Raghav as said, all ports need to flow from the SQ to the AGG and on to the UPD